# debug android studio app on zatec ZA-715E

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, tablet

I have buyed a [tablet ZA-715E](http://www.jumia.ma/zatec-za-715e-7-wi-fi-8-go-2-go-ram-android-4.4-noir-218636.html) and I want to debug my android studio app on it

I have enabled usb debogage and I have looked for its usb driver in [OEM USB Drivers](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) list
and I have installed intel usb driver because this tablet has an intel processor

but always don't see it on running device in choose device popup

Comment: no fix to this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The USB id of your device isn't declared inside the Intel driver, so it will not be automatically picked by your OS. You have to do it manually:

Open your device manager and select "Update Driver Software..." on your device:
[image: Device Manager]

Select "Browse My Computer for driver software":
[image: browse]

Select "Let me pick from a list of drivers on my computer":
[image: manually pick]

Select "Android Device". If not available, it may have been renamed to "Intel Android Device", "Samsung Android Device", and so on.
[image: pick Android Device]

Then, choose the "Android Composite ADB interface" from Intel, Google or in fact almost any other Android devices vendor:
[image: pick Composite ADB interface]

This works because usually, the only differences between all these composite ADB Windows drivers are the usb_id and the signature.

Now adb devices should return your device and a popup will appear on your Android device, to authorize your computer.